# close app on home button & restart fragment

Tags: android, oncreate

i have two simple questions (hope so).

First i want to close my app, when the user hits the homebutton in my HomeFragment, because there is a counter (Days,Hours) and when I click the home Button and come back later there is still the old value.
Then i have to close the app via backbutton and start again. So i want my app to get killed, when I hit the home button.

Then i have a button to delete the last value, on which the counter is based. When I hit the button i want to run my homeFragment again. Should i just create a funnction which calls, the homefragment.onCreate again?

Comment: you cannot get the homebutotn click..you need to use someother workaround for that..

Comment: Your question is unclear, try rephrasing it so that you'll have a chance of getting a good answer

Comment: I have several unix-timestamps in a database. I open my App and there appears for Example my Age. (You are ...Years,..months and so on). Now i press the homebutton and do something else, like a day. When I open my App now there is still the old value. Same when i delete the last timestamp from the database there is still the old value. I want to refresh the fragment, when something changes. For this I have to run HomeFragment again, where all the code is in, like SQ-Lite Query and Time Calculation.

Comment: Now  i got it.

For the problem with the Homebutton i use onRestart, to replace the fragment with the updated version of the Fragment.

For updating in the Fragment, when something changes, i have to put the hole code in a seperate function and just use settext to change just the Text.

Answer (score 0):

> When I hit the button i want to run my homeFragment again. Should i just create a funnction which calls, the homefragment.onCreate again?

No, these functions are meant to be called by the system.
You are probably looking for the onStop() method (also called by the system)

```
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    // clear counter e.g.
    myCounter.setText("");
}
```

Other than this, it's kind of hard to tell what you want. Feel free to add more (if not all) of your code.

Comment: In addition, learn a bit about the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html), absolutely necessary when developing on Android. And for your fragment, use the `FragmentManager` for recreating your fragment